# Xcode: variables populate with breakpoints but not in realtime

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, breakpoints, locationmanager

I have a function that utilizes `LocationManager` for iOS development. The function fulfills the very common purpose of pulling latitude and longitude from the `LocationManager` object and populating some method variables to build a set of directions.

Currently the method works fine on the iOS simulator when there are some specifically placed breakpoints. I will step into each step until I see that the lat and long have been populated and then continue program execution. The view is correctly altered to bring up a set of directions.

If the breakpoints are removed however, the variables are never populated and the view defaults to `0.000` for lat and longitudes.

I also see an error in one of the threads (I'm completely unfamiliar with thread based programming. This is not my app I am debugging): `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE =1, address= {some address}`

Below is the function code (`asdf` is just the instance name for `LocationManager`):

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    asdf = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    asdf.delegate = self;
    asdf.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    asdf.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [asdf startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [asdf location];

    float longitude=location.coordinate.longitude;
    float latitude=location.coordinate.latitude;

    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);

    double userLatitude = latitude;
    double userLongitude = longitude;

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSString *userLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLatitude];
    NSString *userLng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLongitude];
    NSString *destinationLatitude = site.siteGPSN;
    NSString *destinationLongitude = site.siteGPSW;
    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buildMap('%@','%@','%@','%@')",destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, userLat, userLng];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem of asynchronous methods... No delegate methods or usual "asynchrone blocks"?

Comment: I would rip out this code and do it properly i.e. make proper use of the delegate and in particular locationManager:didUpdateLocations:.  And are you also aware that the initial location returned like it is above is cached anyway and thus could be out of date (by possibly hundreds or thousands of miles from your actual current location), thus this code is useless. Find a guide on how to use the location manager and re-implement it then see if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `CLLocationManager` correctly. You need to implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Otherwise there is no guarantee there will be a `location` object cached by the manager when you try to use it.

The implementation would look something like this:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // handle error
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    // use location here
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
       [manager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Remember to call `stopUpdatingLocation` at the appropriate time as well (whenever you are done).

I would recommend looking at Apple's "LocateMe" sample project which provides some great starting code on how to use this protocol correctly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LocateMe/Listings/Classes_GetLocationViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801-Classes_GetLocationViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8

Comment: The code actually already is setting the delegate, its just not making use of it as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Location manager never gets an update as soon as you start it using `startUpdatingLocation` this is when the delegate methods come into action. Delegate methods are invoked only when a location update is available or the process failed for some reason.

I found that you have set:

```
asdf.delegate = self;
```

That means you are registering the current class as a handler for location updates. So you should declare the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol in the header (.h file) of your class, like following:

```
@interface <# Your Class Name #> : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate> // your class might have inherited from anything other than NSObject
////......
@end
```

Now in your implementation file (.m) implement the following methods:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations {
if (!locations || [locations count] == 0) {
    return;
}

CLLocation* location = locations[[locations count] - 1];
if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
    return;
}

    float longitude=location.coordinate.longitude;
    float latitude=location.coordinate.latitude;

    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);

    double userLatitude = latitude;
    double userLongitude = longitude;

    //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; -- dont stop it here

    NSString *userLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLatitude];
    NSString *userLng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLongitude];
    NSString *destinationLatitude = site.siteGPSN;
    NSString *destinationLongitude = site.siteGPSW;
    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buildMap('%@','%@','%@','%@')",destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, userLat, userLng];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation { //for backward compatibility
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }
    float longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    float latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);

    double userLatitude = latitude;
    double userLongitude = longitude;

    //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; -- dont stop it here

    NSString *userLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLatitude];
    NSString *userLng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLongitude];
    NSString *destinationLatitude = site.siteGPSN;
    NSString *destinationLongitude = site.siteGPSW;
    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buildMap('%@','%@','%@','%@')",destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude, userLat, userLng];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"core location error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) { //when location update is not available for that time don't continue receiving updates
        NSLog(@"location service will terminate now");
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

After all these set up, your location manager would invoke the appropriate delegate method when an update is available (or failed) and you can stop your location service when you don't actually need it anymore, may be in your `viewWillDisappear` or `dealloc` methods.

Comment: I am attempting to invoke one of these three appropriate methods that you have provided at viewLoad.  Unfortunately, I am working with limited objective-C experience and limited time.  I have this method that is running at view load (and I assume the appropriate of the above 3 runs next.)  Can you help me understand how to call the appropriate one inside this method body:

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
       //  assuming one of the three above methods you provided runs here

Comment: @user2913845 unfortunately there is no way you can invoke any of this methods, by your own. Even if your web view finishes loading, the location update might not be available at that moment. And its the only time when you can invoke your JS in web view with current location is when the location is available in one of these protocol methods. Like, `webViewDidFinishLoad:` protocol method is invoked by web view, itself and you dont have any control over it, `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:` is similarly invoked by location manager beyond your control.

Comment: @user2913845 If you are struggling with the reference of your web view inside your location manager delegate methods, you can simply hold a property reference of your `webView` to access it globally in your class and the last line of your code would be something like `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];` inside your delegate methods.

Comment: @user2913845 However, if a location update is not available you need to handle the situation gracefully. For example, in my app I had loaded a GMap inside a web view and had used location manager delegate methods to display a direction map from current location to destination. The app simply opens up the map with some random location (may be 0,0). Now when I get a location update inside one of the aforesaid protocol methods, I invoke a JS to set map center to that location and display the direction accordingly. However, if the update is not available my code just sits idle invoking no JS.